# Angular Service in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I've yet to find decent documentation detailing how to migrate from Angular 1.x to Aurelia. So far, I've only seen folks detailing how the concept of an Angular `directive` can be remade in Aurelia using `@customElement`. Okay, simple enough. But these examples always, always just mock data.

That said, Angular Services are singletons that can be injected into any controller/directive/service, and typically allows for the fetching of data from a server (i.e. `PersonService`, `OrdersService`).

But how are these `data services` modeled in Aurelia? Is everything just a class? It [seems like it](http://patrickwalters.net/my-best-practices-for-aurelia-solving-the-m-in-mvvm/).

Essentially, I'd to see some code samples, a `hello-world`, that effectively fetches data from a service, and provides it to a `@customElement`. Where do the HTTP calls go? How do we even make HTTP calls? Angular uses `$http`, what about Aurelia?

**EDIT**:

Here's a simple angular service. How would one attack this in Aurelia?

```
app.service('SomeDataService', function () {
    return {
        getMyData: function (options) {
            return $.ajax(options);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Some Angular `hello-world` code won't hurt, I guess. The question looks too vague in its current state.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a simple angular service that fetches data with $.ajax. Wondering how this would be mimicked in Aurelia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep- plain ES6/ES7 classes.  There's no framework intrusion in your data services.

**my-data-service.js**

```js
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client'; // or 'aurelia-fetch-client' if you want to use fetch
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class MyDataService {
  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getMyData() {
    return this.http.get(someUrl);
  }
}
```

**fancy-custom-element.js**

```js
import {MyDataService} from './my-data-service';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(MyDataService) // aurelia's dependency injection container will inject the same MyDataService instance into each instance of FancyCustomElement
export class FancyCustomElement {
  data = null;

  constructor(dataService) {
    this.dataService = dataService;
  }

  // perhaps a button click is bound to this method:
  loadTheData() {
    this.dataService.getMyData()
      .then(data => this.data = data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. I have a question about `import` in `fancy-custom-element.js`. First, we import the `MyDataService`, then we import `inject`. Seems a bit redundant, no? If I import a service, chances are I want to inject it. Would there ever be a time when I would want to import the service, but not inject it? Trying to think of a scenario...

Comment: Good question, in practice there are often a bunch of imports, many are static items eg `import moment from 'moment';`. It would be unsafe to assume all imports need to be injected into the constructor. Especially if you had multiple class exports in the same file.  If you were to use TypeScript you could replace `@inject(MyDataService)` with `@autoInject()` and aurelia would discover the constructor's arguments using the metadata emitted by the typescript transpiler.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense, especially in the context of importing moment or something like that. Thanks again!